# Adding variable to JSX string

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm returning the following HTML in React.

```
<div 
    className={ props.className } 
    data-slide='{"arrows": true, "slidesToShow": 3, "slidesToScroll": 1}'>
</div>
```

It returns the following which is ok

```
<div class="some-class" data-slide="{"arrows": true, "slidesToShow": 3, "slidesToScroll": 1}"></div>
```

However, I want the value for `arrows` to be a variable named `arrowsVal` which I'm setting in my React component.

I tried:

```
<div 
    className={ props.className } 
    data-slide='{"arrows":' + arrowsVal + ', "slidesToShow": 3, "slidesToScroll": 1}'>
</div>
```

and

```
<div 
  className={ props.className } 
  data-slide='{"arrows": `${arrowsVal}`, "slidesToShow": 3, "slidesToScroll": 1}'>
</div>
```

but it does not work.

Comment: You'll probably get a few different answers to this, but in general, when I need to perform logic/processing within JSX, I try to do it in a separate function that I call within the brackets. so, `data-slide={createDataSlideString()}`, and then before your `render`'s `return()`, `function createDataSlideString(){...code that creates your string}`. This makes it easier to avoid JSX character-escape issues in your expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work i think

```js
<div 
  className={ props.className } 
  data-slide={`{"arrows": ${arrowsVal}, "slidesToShow": 3, "slidesToScroll": 1}`}>
</div>
```

However the approach that i would recommend is to define a const before return statement of Render method defined as:

```js
const dataSlide = `{"arrows": ${arrowsVal}, "slidesToShow": 3, "slidesToScroll": 1}`
```

and render it as:

```html
<div 
  className={ props.className } 
  data-slide={dataSlide}>
</div>
```

I hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks! Is there any particular reason for defining a const first? Rather than just adding it to return.

Comment: It's juste more helpful for readability because it offers less code in your return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<div
  className={props.className}
  data-slide={{ arrows: arrowsVal, slidesToShow: 3, slidesToScroll: 1 }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div 
  className={ props.className } 
  data-slide={{
    arrows: arrowsVal,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
  }}
/>
```

if you need data-slide to be a string anyway

```
<div 
  className={ props.className } 
  data-slide={`{"arrows": ${arrowsVal}, "slidesToShow": 3, "slidesToScroll": 1}`}
/>
```